# a simple php form in a dialog box or a pop up

Tags: jquery, dialog

Hii ,
           I have a small php form. I need it to come in  a pop up(dialog) when  a user clicks a link .how do i do this using jquery .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [jquery UI](http://jqueryui.com) Dialog

```
$(function() {
   $('#myLink').click( function() {
        $('<div title="Warning: A dialog"><p>Dialog contents</p></div>').dialog({
                autoOpen: true,
                modal: true, // or false
                close: function() { $(this).dialog('destroy') } ),
                ... other options ...
        });
    });
});
```

If you need the dialog contents to be dynamic, you can use `get()` to load some html from the server and set the HTML of the dialog from it or just construct the contents dynamically from elements on the page, if that's more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Hey, just look for jquery and dialog, this comes up: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog
(I just assume you mean a HTML form as I don't know what you mean by 'php form'. php doesn't have forms)

Comment: i meant to say i have a form in  page called login.php

and when i click on link like this

<a href='/login.php' class='dialog'>Pradeep</a>

its hould open the login.php page in a dialog box